# $A$ and $B$ are the positive acute angles satisfying the equations $3\cos^2 A + 2\cos^2 B=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$A$ and $B$ are the positive acute angles satisfying the equations $3\cos^2 A + 2\cos^2 B=4$ and $\dfrac {3\sin A}{\sin B}=\dfrac {2\cos B}{\cos A}$. Then $A+2B$ is equal to:

$1$. $\dfrac {\pi}{4}$

$2$. $\dfrac {\pi}{3}$

$3$. $\dfrac {\pi}{6}$

$4$. $\dfrac {\pi}{2}$.

My Attempt

$$\dfrac {3\sin A}{\sin B}=\dfrac {2\cos B}{\cos A}$$
$$3\sin A.\cos A= 2\cos B.\sin B$$
$$\dfrac {3}{2} \sin 2A=2\sin 2B$$.

How do I proceed further?

Answer (score 2):

From the first equation

$$\cos  2B = 2\cos ^2B - 1=\left(4-3\cos ^2A\right)-1=3\sin ^2A$$

From the second equation

$$\sin  2B = \frac{3}{2}\sin  2A$$

Replace these values in

$$\cos (A+2B)=\cos  A \cos  2B - \sin  A \sin  2B=$$

$$=\cos  A \left(3\sin ^2A\right)-\sin  A \left(\frac{3}{2}\sin  2A\right)=0$$

$$A+2B=\frac{\pi }{2}$$

Comment: Unique & logical.But the answer seems to know that $\cos(A+2B)$ is going to be zero?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we have:

$$\frac{3\sin\left(\text{A}\right)}{\sin\left(\text{B}\right)}=\frac{2\cos\left(\text{B}\right)}{\cos\left(\text{A}\right)}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space3\sin\left(\text{A}\right)\cos\left(\text{A}\right)=2\cos\left(\text{B}\right)\sin\left(\text{B}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\frac{3\sin\left(2\text{A}\right)}{2}=\sin\left(2\text{B}\right)\tag1$$

Now, we also have:

$$3\cos^2\left(\text{A}\right)+2\cos^2\left(\text{B}\right)=1+3\cdot\frac{1+\cos\left(2\text{A}\right)}{2}+\cos\left(2\text{B}\right)=4\tag2$$

Answer (score 1):

The first condition gives $3\cos2A+2\cos2B=3$.

The second condition gives $3\sin2A=2\sin2B$ or 
$$9\sin^22A=4\sin^22B$$ or
$$9(1-\cos^22A)=4(1-\cos^22B)$$ or
$$9\cos^22A-4\cos^22B=5$$ or
$$(3\cos2A+2\cos2B)(3\cos2A-2\cos2B)=5$$ or
$$3(3\cos2A-2\cos2B)=5$$ or
$$3\cos2A-2\cos2B=\frac{5}{3},$$
which after summing with $$3\cos2A+2\cos2B=3$$ gives $6\cos2A=\frac{14}{3}$,
which says $\cos2A=\frac{7}{9}$ and $\cos2B=\frac{1}{3}$.

Thus,
$$\sin(A+2B)=\sin{A}\cos2B+\cos{A}\sin2B=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{7}{9}}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{7}{9}}{2}}\cdot\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{9}}=1,$$

which gives $A+2B=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: How did you get the values of $\cos 2A$ and $\cos 2B$?

Comment: @Albert Einstein I fixed my post. See now.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: Square both sides of the second equation, and and replace $\sin^2 $ by $1 - \cos^2$, and coupled with the first solve a system of equations for $\cos A, \cos B$. Can you manager to proceed?

Comment: what does it mean " together with the first"?